Calculate IR refractive index (NK)
I'm a new user of Materials Studio and trying to use CASTEP to calculate the IR refractive index of $\ce{SiO_2}$, in which optical phonon effects are very important. Experimental data shows an absorption region around $\lambda=8\,\mu m$. However, the CASTEP document indicates that phonons and their optical effects have been neglected. As a result, the calculated absorption is always 0 in the IR range.
I wonder if it's possible to calculate the IR refractive index considering optical phonon effects in CASTEP, or if other software is available to do that.

+1. Welcome to our community.

@Camps you guys have mhchem turned on so I added the syntax for chemicals.

Yes,I think this is possible within CASTEP. I presume that you have run the "efield" or "spectral" task to extract the electronic contribution to the dielectric function, and that is what the docs will have talked about. As you say, this doesn't (by default) calculate the phonon contributions because these are vastly more expensive than the electronic contributions.
I believe the "phonon+efield" task will calculate the phonon contribution to the dielectric constant.
Hope that helps,
Rob
